# list of custom post types under another custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown

I have a custom post type named as products, and it has a dropdown metabox option for another custom post type named as online-shops (e.g. Shop 1, Shop 2, Shop 3, etc). I am able to successfully save the metabox key and value to the database.

On the single-onlineshops.php, I have a section of product gallery. Is it possible to create a loop list of products under the single post template?

Currently here are my function snippets:

```
        function MSB_custom_meta_box() {
        //another add_meta_box here
        add_meta_box("featured-products", "Featured Products", "featured_product_metabox", "product", "normal", "high", null);
    }
    add_action("add_meta_boxes", "MSB_custom_meta_box");

    save_featured_product_metabox ($post_id, $post, $update) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['online_shop_select'] ) ) { // Input var okay.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'online_shop_select', sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['online_shop_select'] ) ) ); //
    Input var okay. }
    } 
    add_action ("save_post", "save_featured_product_metabox", 10, 3); 

    function featured_product_metabox ($post) { 
        wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "featured-product-nonce"); ?>

        <label for="online_shop_select">Select Seed Bank</label>
        <?php 
            $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID);
            $online_shop_select = ( isset( $meta['online_shop_select'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['online_shop_select'][0] ) ? $meta['online_shop_select'][0] : '';
            $args_pages = array(
                'post_type'             => 'online-shops',
                'depth'                 => 0,
                'child_of'              => 0,
                'selected'              => $online_shop_select,
                'echo'                  => 1,
                'name'                  => 'online_shop_select',
                'id'                    => 'online_shop_select',
                'class'                 => null,
                'show_option_none'      => null,
                'show_option_no_change' => null,
                'option_none_value'     => esc_html__( '&ndash; Select &ndash;', THEME_SLUG ),
            ); 
            wp_dropdown_pages($args_pages); ?>
    <br>
    <?php }
```

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you can always use wp_query to get what your looking for -

Comment: yeah I figured out what I was looking for. I used this instead $meta_value = $post->ID;
                        $args = array (
                            'post_type' => 'product',
                            'meta_key' => 'online_shop_select',
                            'meta_value' => $meta_value
                        );

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to solve it by this code:

```
    $meta_value = $post->ID;
                    $args = array (
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'meta_key' => 'online_shop_select',
                        'meta_value' => $meta_value
                    );
```